# How do I add to a mapping that maps (address => bool)?

Tags: solidity

This is just part of my contract, but shows where I create the mapping, the modifier onlyMember, and the function addMember.  Basically, I want to be able to add new members who can execute onlyMember functions, as I - the owner - can. 
 I was able to add a new member, as the owner, but when I switched to the member address and tried to execute other functions that appear later in the contract (which have the modifier onlyMember attached to them), I get an error.  I am wondering if I set up the addMember function incorrectly, but remix isn't giving me any errors about it.

```
// <------------------------- MEMBERS ------------------------->

address owner = msg.sender;
bool ifmember;
mapping(address => bool) members;

modifier onlyMember {
    require(msg.sender == owner || members[msg.sender] == true);
    _;
    }

function addMember(address _address) public onlyMember {
    ifmember = members[_address];
    }

// <----------------------- END MEMBERS ----------------------->
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing syntactically wrong with your addMember function so Remix won't give you any errors, but it's not really doing anything.

This line:

```
ifmember = members[_address];
```

is just setting the variable `ifmember` equal to the value of `members[_address]`. In the code you provided there's nothing changing the value of `members[_address]`.

I'm not sure what `ifmember` is supposed to be doing, but I tihnk you want this for your `addMember` function:

```
function addMember(address _address) public onlyMember {
    members[_address] = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am new to bools and thought I had to declare it before using it.